# Hibernate Search cannot encode properly after saving data

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-search

I am working on a `Spring Boot` project with `Hibernate Search`. When I save any records into my database, it works fine. But when I open `Lucene` index by `Luke`, it seems like the value is not encoded. I have set all the properties of Hibernate in `application.properties` but it does not work as well. Can someone help me with this problem? Thanks

This is the analysed field

```
@Analyzer(definition = "TagCustomAnalyzer")
    @Field(store = Store.YES)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "nvarchar(255)")
    private String name;
```

TagCustomAnalyzer

```
@AnalyzerDef(
        name = "TagCustomAnalyzer",
        tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),
        filters = {
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class),
        }
)
```

My `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.CharSet=UTF-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:log4jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=MyDatabase;characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

It saves ok, the row inside my database is encoded but inside lucene index opened by Luke, it shows this

[This seems to be not encoded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXJjt.png)

These are four fields that. `title` and `contentWithoutHtmlTags` are encoded, but the others (which are typed from other browser) are not

[This is what i see in lucene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64zrh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. When testing I use `Unikey` so when the text goes to lucene index, it cannot be indexed properly.

[Make sure if you use any kinds of text encode just set it back to Unicode mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D1D8.png)

Answer (score 1):

Two things I'm not certain about:

1. Are you sure Luke, and particularly your version of Luke, supports UTF-8?
2. Are you sure your `ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory` did not mess up the string before it is indexed?

Regardless of that, I'm not sure why you decided to check the stored value directly. It might be that values are encoded in what looks like garbage, but are always re-encoded as necessary when they are retrieved from the index.

How do you plan to retrieve the stored values? If you want to use [Hibernate Search projections](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#projections), can you try that and tell us if the projected value is correctly encoded?

Note that the application properties you showed do not matter in this case: they are only used by Hibernate ORM, not by Hibernate Search.

Comment: I use Luke 5.5 cus I want to see the text after being indexed whether it is able to point to the row I save or not. It's kinda strange because other records are indexed correctly, but when a friend of mine tries to type something in his browser and then sends that text to my `Spring Boot` server, Hibernate cannot index that.

Comment: I added the last image in the question. Luke does support UTF-8 but I don't know why this text cannot be encoded. Do I have to re-encode any String inside request body each time I receive a request ?

Comment: Judging from your question update, the problem is definitely related to your analyzer. Try to use the same analyzer as the `title` field, then progressively change it to what you want. One of your changes will trigger the problem again, and you'll know what not to do. I'd bet on the `AsciiFoldingFilter`.

Comment: I've fixed this and the bug is so dumb. My friend used Unikey and he set  `compound Unikey` mode so when it comes to Hibernate, it cannot index this, otherwise it's ok, just setting `Unikey` mode is enough